# pressure washer hose connector/adapter

Tags: pressure-washer

I am trying to use a greenworks wand with another pressure washer. I am not able to connect them. The picture shows the ends of the hose and the wand. I would like to know if an adapter is available to connect them. I can even cut the hose and attach a compatible connector. The attached image has the details. Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: What is exact cause of it not fitting, too big, not big enough, too long?  You are releasing the lock(green u-shape thingy)?

Comment: The pressure washer hose end is horribly out of focus. There was another question on your type of connectors in the last day or so all my pressure washers have screw together pressure fittings I am guessing the out of focus one may be that style.